# SDL2 confusion with pointers c

Tags: c, pointers, sdl

I'm trying to program a basic game with SDL2 library and I am getting a little bit confused with a basic concept.

Basically I would like to make a function:

```
void quit_clean (SDL_Window *window, SDL_Renderer *renderer)
{
 if (renderer != NULL)
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
 if (window != NULL)
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

 exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

I would call this function each time there is an error so I can free the renderer and the window properly before to quit the program
e.g.

```
texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, tmp);
if(texture==NULL){
      printf ("SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface Error: : %s\n", SDL_GetError());
      quit_clean (&window, &renderer);
}
```

Where I am getting confused is if I need to call this function from another function how does it work ?

To be precise I would have:

1. My main() function where I create my *window and my *renderer
2. a new my_function() called from main() in which I would among other stuffs create a texture from a surface and test errors
3. and finally my quit_clean() function called from my_function() in case of error.

The way I see it, in order to pass my window and my renderer from main() to quit_clean() using my_function() the prototypes would be then:

```
void my_function (SDL_Window **window, SDL_Renderer **renderer);
void quit_clean (SDL_Window ***window, SDL_Renderer ***renderer);
```

Am I correct or not?
If yes then how could I call this function from main() if needed.

If I call "quit_clean (&window, &renderer);" from my main() the types are not correct anymore then.

Or maybe I could create pointers from window and renderer and pass those pointers to quit_clean(). I don't know I'm confused, I'm not sure if my thought process is correct.

Do you have any tips for this kind of situation?

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to StackOverflow.  I am not clear as to what your question is -- why do you think you need to change the prototype to take a pointer to a pointer?  From the description it does not sound as though you need to, but perhaps I am not fully understanding you....

Comment: Hi @Basya thank you. That's the thing I am not really sure if I have to change the prototype. In my mind when I destroy my window in quit_clean() I am modifying my pointer *window , and in order to do that I thought I had to create a pointer of a pointer. But I could be wrong. sorry if I was not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the double pointer as arguments to your functions:

```
int my_function (SDL_Window *window, SDL_Renderer *renderer);
int quit_clean (SDL_Window *window, SDL_Renderer *renderer);
```

As you might have noticed, i've added a return type (int), because every function should return a result, indicating success or failure.

Secondly, it would be better not to call the `quit_clean` function from other functions, instead, if you encounter an error in for e.g. `my_function`, return an error and call the `quit_clean` function in the main function.

Like this:

```
int main() 
{
    SDL_Window *window = NULL; 
    SDL_Renderer *renderer = NULL;

    window = SDL_CreateWindow(...); 

    if (window) {

        renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, ...);

        if (renderer) {

            int err = my_function(window, renderer);

            if (!err) { //success: 0, error: -1
                //do what is needed to be done
            }

        }

    }

    //finally clean up, 
    //no matter the case (either due to error or program termination)
    quit_clean(window, renderer);

    return 0;
}
```

In the `quit_clean` function you have to check the passed arguments (although i think that SDL checks them too, but better than sorry):

```
int quit_clean (SDL_Window *window, SDL_Renderer *renderer)
{
    //other cleanup first

    //finally
    if (renderer != NULL)
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    if (window != NULL)
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

And for clarity an example of `my_function`:

```
int my_function (SDL_Window *window, SDL_Renderer *renderer)
{
    if (some_condition_does_not_hold)
        return -1;

    //do your stuff
    //never call quit_clean if something goes wrong, return either -1 or
    //some other (previously defined) negative error number

    //finally
    return 0; //success
}
```

Comment: I think this answer is correct; I would just suggest using, for the return value, either a boolean (true/false only) or an enum defining success and error values. That would make cleaner and more understandable code.

Comment: Sure, whatever seems to make the code cleaner. I took the standard c functions as example, where mostly 0 (zero) indicates success and -1 stands for error, where the `errno` variable is set to the reason.

Comment: Yes, that is the standard library approach; I think people have come up with a few good ideas since then though :-)  Anyway, it was just a suggestion...

Comment: Don't get me wrong, i appreciate your contribution. I simply explained, why i used that kind of example.

Comment: Thanks you for your suggestions guys I've definitely learned new things here. Also I try to focus on writing clean codes in order to take good habits so I appreciate the tips